# How to assign a number to an object in an array?

Tags: java

package chapter10;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Customer {
    private String name;
    private  String streetAddress;   
    private  String phoneNumber;
    private  int total;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }      

    public  String getStreetAddress(){
        return streetAddress;
    }

    public void setStreetAddress(String streetAddress) {
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }



    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public int getTotal(){  
        return total;       
    }

    public void setTotal(int total){
        this.total = total; 
    }

    public static void assign(){
        int a = (int) (Math.random() + 10); 
        int r = (int) (Math.random() + 10); 
        int f = (int) (Math.random() + 10); 
        System.out.println(a + r + f + "x" + "x" + "x");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList <Customer > customerList = new ArrayList <Customer>();
        char ans;
        do
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer(); 
            System.out.print("Customer name ");
            customer.setName(in.next());
int i = 0;
++i;
            System.out.print("Street Address ");
            customer.setStreetAddress(in.next());

            System.out.print("Phone Number ");
            customer.setPhoneNumber(in.next());

            customerList.add(customer);
            System.out.println("Enter total sales ");
            customer.setTotal(in.nextInt());

            System.out.println("Would you like to enter in a new customer       (    y/n)? ");
            String answer = in.next();
            ans = answer.charAt(0);
           ((String) customerList).concat("")

        } while(ans == 'y');

        for(Customer c: customerList){
            System.out.print(c.getName() + "\n" + "Phone number is         "            +c    .getPhoneNumber() +"\n" + "Total sales is "+ c.getTotal() + "\n" + "Address       is"+ c.getStreetAddress());

        }

        for(int i=0; i<customerList.size(); i++){
            //System.out.print(customerList.get(i).getName());
        }
    }
}
```

I need to assign a number to each value in the arraylist but i am getting an error that says that I have to convert to string (arraylist). How do I add it?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Don't just dump your entire code here and expect us to find the error for you.

Comment: You sending me this message because you are looking for a generalized theme of people throwing their entire project up here. This is different because I know what is correct and incorrect in my code and i know that me adding a feature caused a problem. My question requires the entire code because it provides background on why I need to avoid simply switching the arraytype to String which would solve my problem. I would appreciate it if you  could provide a hint in the right direction instead giving the same canned answer that you give to everyone else.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign a number"? You are already assigning a phone number and total in the main method. Your question in the current form is way too vague to answer...

Comment: Add 3 random numbers one through 10 and three XXX's

Comment: 678xxx = it is a customernumber

Comment: So you want a field that's not a phoneNumber but is a customerNumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what I gather from the comments is correct then I believe this is what you want:

Your current assign() is incorrect if you want random values 1-10, it should look like this instead:

```
public String assign(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int a = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
    int r = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
    int f = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
    return a+r+f+"xxx";
}
```

Customer will look like this:

```
public class Customer {
    private String name;
    private String customerNumber;
    private  String streetAddress;   
    private  String phoneNumber;
    private  int total;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    public String getCustomerNumber() { return this.customerNumber; }
    public void setCustomerNumber(String cNumber) { this.customerNumber = cNumber; }
```

And assigning the numbers should look like this:

```
    for(Customer c : customerList) {
        c.setCustomerNumber(assign());
    }
```

Also avoid this line of code, it's a really bad idea:

```
    ((String) customerList).concat("")
```

You should probably rename the customerNumber to customerID.

Answer (score 1):

Hiiii

As i understand you are trying to to add number to each value to arrayList ,And same time you are creating arrayList of customer object, So first understand about arrayList of object,

```
Customer c1 = new Customer();
Customer c2 = new Customer();
ArrayList<Customer> al = new ArrayList();

al.add(c1);
al.add(c2);
```

Here this ArrayList object save only address of customer object so how can you change the address of Customer object ; You can not add number in Customer type ArrayList Object,
There is another way typecast your ArrayList to Object type and then no need to typecast again , you can add any type of object in ArrayList
like this,

```
Customer c1 = new Customer();
    Customer c2 = new Customer();
    ArrayList<Object> al = new ArrayList();

    al.add(c1);
    al.add(c2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there's the following line:

```
((String) customerList).concat("")
```

Trying to cast a List to a String is doomed to failure - I'm not sure why do you think it should work.

If you want a String representation of the list, you should implement a [toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java) method in class `Customer` and then you can do something like:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(customerList.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ArrayList, you can use Map. In which you can have the number as key and value as Customer.

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-map-example/ Contains the example of using Map

Answer in [Storing a new object as the value of a hashmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099843/storing-a-new-object-as-the-value-of-a-hashmap) contains info about how to use Object as value in HashMap