# How to use an object's class variables to identify an object in java?

Tags: java

I created a class and made 57 objects from it, each one has specific ID number.

Can I create a method which returns an object using an ID as the argument?

For example, assume the name of my class is `Things` and I made two object from it called `apple` and `dog`, they have IDs `1` and `2`.

`Things.java`:

```
class Things {

    private String name;
    private int ID;

    public Things(String name, int ID) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
```

`Main.java`:

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Things apple = new Things("apple", 1);
        Things dog = new Things("dog", 2);
    }
}
```

in this example I want to create a method in class "Things" which returns object apple if I use 1 as argument and object dog if I use 2 .

Comment: a `Map<Integer,Things>` like <id,object> can be used; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: Return the `Things` instance from where? You have nothing that *contains* `apple` and `dog`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing a new object as the value of a hashmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099843/storing-a-new-object-as-the-value-of-a-hashmap)

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank  I edited my question .

Comment: What you ask for in your edit makes no sense. In fact, the name of your class is wrong. You don't have `Things` but two instances of `Thing`: `apple` and `dog`. Each `Thing` only knows itself, it has no idea that there is a second `Thing`. Use the `ThingRepository` approach outlined in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot identify objects by a particular property unless you store it in a special repository

You can create a `ThingRepository` and can get specific `Things` by the id.

```
public class ThingRepository {
   private Map<Integer, Things> thingsRepository = new HashMap<>();

   public void addThing(int id, Things things) {
      thingsRepository.put(id, things);
   } 
   public Things getThingById(int id) {
       return thingsRepository.get(id); //Can return null if not present
   }
}
```

The `addThing` method need not explicitly take the `id`. If you add a getter to `Things`, then it can be simplified to

```
public void addThing(Things things) {
    thingsRepository.put(things.getId(), things);
}
```

Couple of problems you need to address:

1. Each created `Things` object has to be added to this somehow (either the caller needs to add or there must be some other wrapper/factory that must do this).
2. Once a `Things` is not needed, it must be removed from the above map, else it can lead to memory leak.

---

Btw, shouldn't `Things` be named as just a `Thing`?

Comment: Maybe remove the `int id` parameters from `addThing`. The `Things` has the `ID` member, only the getter is missing.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank Of course. Modified my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are **two** aspects here:

- you need some sort of **data** structure that remembers about created objects, and allows you to access them by id, for example a simple `Map<Integer, Things>`. Each time you create a new `Things` (should better be called `Thing`, shouldn't it?!), you go `thatMap.put(newId, newThing)`.
- if you want that data to "survive", you would have to somehow persist it (like writing data to a file, database, ...)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Intellij for example press: alt + insert and choose getters/setter.

If not just write your own getters/setter ;).

Like here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html

But basically if you want to look for Thing with particular Id you need to store somewhere them for example in ArrayList, then iterate through it and if your find element with that Id just return it.

1) Create new ArrayList

2) Iterate through

3) If you find Thing with Id you want, return it.

Comment: A setter is not useful to get an instance using the ID as the argument.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank that's true

Comment: Yes, using some kind of container is possible. You could edit your answer and explain this approach.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He doesnt want to know how to generate getters and setters.

Comment: Iterating of a List is a bad answer.