# Unable to initialize new List as value of a Map with the :: Operator?

Tags: java, maps, java-stream, collectors, scope-resolution

While working on a card game project, I was trying to create a new Map while already having a List I wanted to use as a KeySet. The Map has to use Keys of type Player and have each of them hold a Value consisting of a single `List<Trick>`, with Player being an Interface and Trick - a class.

Initially I tried to use a Stream of the `List<Player> players` I had and then collect it to a Map in the following way:

```
private Map<Player, List<Trick>> playerTricks = players.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, ArrayList::new));
```

My IDE, IntelliJ, however did not allow me this format, as it said "Cannot resolve Constructor ArrayList".

Much to my surprise, the IDE stopped complaining when I removed the `::`-Operator:

```
(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> new ArrayList<Trick>()));
```

While I now do have code with no Exceptions, I still can't understand why the Scope Resolution Operator would produce such an error. I'd be grateful if anyone was to explain it properly.

**P.S.** 
While searching to a solution, I found this StackOverflow Thread:

[Storing a new object as the value of a hashmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099843/storing-a-new-object-as-the-value-of-a-hashmap)

It does concern a similar issue, but doesn't really address the problem I was facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [second parameter of `Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) takes a `Function` that takes the stream type and maps it to the value type of the new `Map`.

> ```
> Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper
> ```

First, `::` isn't called the scope resolution operator like in C++, although it functions somewhat similarly when creating a *method reference* in Java.  It's just (simply) "double-colon operator".

The method reference `ArrayList::new` doesn't match `Function<Player, List<Trick>>`, because there is no `ArrayList(Player)` constructor.  This method reference cannot be used.  You're attempting to ignore the `Player` argument, but the method reference must use it.

When you replaced the method reference with a lambda expression `x -> new ArrayList<Trick>()`, that does match `Function<Player, List<Trick>>`.  You're taking `x`, which is implicitly defined to be `Player`, and the type of the lambda expression is `List<Trick>`, which matches.  You're ignoring the `Player` `x` in the lambda expression, before it would even get to the call to create a new `ArrayList`.

Your lambda expression is *not* equivalent to the method reference, because your method reference attempts to find a `ArrayList(Player)` constructor while the lambda expression takes the `Player` and ignores it while just calling the no-arg `ArrayList` constructor explicitly.

Comment: Ahh, I see it now. My mistake was basically thinking that the method reference would simply ignore the `x` and create a new `ArrayList` instance anyway. So even though the lambda does not use the `x` in the constructor call, it is still a valid mapping. Thank you!

Comment: @VasilAlistarov it’s important to be aware of this pitfall, which may happen at other places expecting a `Function` as well (e.g. `Map.computeIfAbsent`). When the function argument happens to be an `Integer`, the method reference *does* find a matching constructor, but it won’t drop the argument as intended, but interpret it as initial capacity. This may happen to work for some input and then suddenly fail with `OutOfMemoryError`…